# Dashboard for running programs in JavaFX 8

Tags: java, java-8, javafx

I have decided to create a dashboard view of a number of running processes/programs/applications, because it became tedious to monitor a bunch of applications, which I had to boot up manually.

Please keep in mind that the .fxml files have been autogenerated using *JavaFX SceneBuilder 2.0* and hence may not have proper formatting, but are necessary if you want to run the program.

I'd like a review on all aspects and the design may also be reviewed if you wish, but I'm not a GUI designer.

**Dashboard.java**

```
public class Dashboard extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Dashboard.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("DPC2 Dashboard");
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**DashboardTabPaneController.java**

```
public class DashboardTabPaneController {
    @FXML
    private Button button;

    @FXML
    private TextArea textArea;

    public Button getButton() {
        return button;
    }

    public TextArea getTextArea() {
        return textArea;
    }
}
```

**Server.java**

```
public class Server {
    private final String name;
    private final List<String> commands;
    private final ProcessBuilder processBuilder;

    private boolean running = false;
    private Runnable startHandler = () -> {};
    private Runnable stopHandler = () -> {};

    public Server() {
        this.name = null;
        this.commands = null;
        this.processBuilder = null;
    }
    private Process process;

    public Server(final String name, final List<String> commands) {
        this.name = Objects.requireNonNull(name, "name");
        this.commands = Objects.requireNonNull(commands, "commands");
        this.processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
    }

    public void setStartHandler(final Runnable startHandler) {
        this.startHandler = Objects.requireNonNull(startHandler, "startHandler");
    }

    public void setStopHandler(final Runnable stopHandler) {
        this.stopHandler = Objects.requireNonNull(stopHandler, "stopHandler");
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public List<String> getCommands() {
        return commands;
    }

    public boolean isRunning() {
        return running;
    }

    public Process getProcess() {
        return process;
    }

    public void start() {
        if (running) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("server " + name + " is already running");
        }
        try {
            process = processBuilder.start();
            setRunning(true);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new UncheckedIOException(ex);
        }
        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                process.waitFor();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
            setRunning(false);
        }).start();
    }

    public void stop() {
        if (!running) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("server " + name + " is not running");
        }
        process.destroyForcibly();
        try {
            process.waitFor();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
        setRunning(false);
    }

    private void setRunning(final boolean value) {
        running = value;
        if (value) {
            startHandler.run();
        }
        else {
            stopHandler.run();
        }
    }
}
```

**DashboardController.java**

```
public class DashboardController implements Initializable {
    private final static String GENERAL_BUTTON_ENABLE = "Start all servers";
    private final static String GENERAL_BUTTON_DISABLE = "Stop all servers";

    private final static String SERVER_BUTTON_ENABLE = "Start server";
    private final static String SERVER_BUTTON_DISABLE = "Stop server";

    private final static List<Server> DEFAULT_SERVERS = new ArrayList<>();
    static {
        DEFAULT_SERVERS.add(new Server("Ping Test", Arrays.asList("C:/Windows/System32/ping", "localhost")));
    }

    private final static DateTimeFormatter DATE_TIME_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

    private final List<Server> servers = new ArrayList<>();
    private final Map<Server, Tab> serverTabs = new HashMap<>();
    private final Map<Server, DashboardTabPaneController> serverControllers = new HashMap<>();

    public DashboardController() {
        this.servers.addAll(DEFAULT_SERVERS);
    }

    @FXML
    private TabPane tabPane;

    @FXML
    private Button generalButton;

    @FXML
    private TextArea textArea;

    @Override
    public void initialize(final URL url, final ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        generalButton.setText(GENERAL_BUTTON_ENABLE);
        servers.forEach(this::createTab);
        servers.forEach(server -> {
            server.setStartHandler(() -> {
                Platform.runLater(() -> writeToGeneralTextArea("Started server " + server.getName() + "."));
                Platform.runLater(() -> serverControllers.get(server).getButton().setText(SERVER_BUTTON_DISABLE));
                if (servers.stream().anyMatch(Server::isRunning)) {
                    Platform.runLater(() -> generalButton.setText(GENERAL_BUTTON_DISABLE));
                }
            });
            server.setStopHandler(() -> {
                Platform.runLater(() -> writeToGeneralTextArea("Stopped server " + server.getName() + "."));
                Platform.runLater(() -> serverControllers.get(server).getButton().setText(SERVER_BUTTON_ENABLE));
                if (servers.stream().noneMatch(Server::isRunning)) {
                    Platform.runLater(() -> generalButton.setText(GENERAL_BUTTON_ENABLE));
                }
            });
        });
    }

    private void createTab(final Server server) {
        Tab tab = new Tab(server.getName());
        try {
            FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("DashboardTabPane.fxml"));
            Node dashboardTabPane = fxmlLoader.load();
            DashboardTabPaneController controller = fxmlLoader.getController();
            controller.getButton().setText(SERVER_BUTTON_ENABLE);
            controller.getButton().addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, mouseEvent -> handleServerButtonAction(server, controller.getButton(), mouseEvent));
            serverControllers.put(server, controller);
            tab.setContent(dashboardTabPane);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new UncheckedIOException(ex);
        }
        serverTabs.put(server, tab);
        tabPane.getTabs().add(tab);
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleGeneralButtonAction(final MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
        switch (generalButton.getText()) {
            case GENERAL_BUTTON_ENABLE:
                generalButton.setText(GENERAL_BUTTON_DISABLE);
                startAllServers();
                break;
            case GENERAL_BUTTON_DISABLE:
                generalButton.setText(GENERAL_BUTTON_ENABLE);
                stopAllServers();
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalStateException("Impossible string for " + generalButton + " / string = " + generalButton.getText());
        }
    }

    private void handleServerButtonAction(final Server server, final Button button, final MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
        switch (button.getText()) {
            case SERVER_BUTTON_ENABLE:
                startServer(server);
                break;
            case SERVER_BUTTON_DISABLE:
                stopServer(server);
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalStateException("Impossible string for " + button + " / string = " + button.getText());
        }
    }

    private void startAllServers() {
        servers.stream()
                .filter(server -> !server.isRunning())
                .forEach(this::startServer);
    }

    private void stopAllServers() {
        servers.stream()
                .filter(server -> server.isRunning())
                .forEach(this::stopServer);
    }

    private void startServer(final Server server) {
        server.start();
        connectServerToTextArea(server, server.getProcess().getInputStream());
        connectServerToTextArea(server, server.getProcess().getErrorStream());
    }

    private void stopServer(final Server server) {
        server.stop();
    }

    private void writeToGeneralTextArea(final String text) {
        Platform.runLater(() -> textArea.appendText("[" + DATE_TIME_FORMATTER.format(LocalDateTime.now()) + "] " + text + System.lineSeparator()));
    }

    private void connectServerToTextArea(final Server server, final InputStream inputStream) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(inputStream, "inputStream");
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        new Thread(() -> {
            bufferedReader.lines()
                    .forEach(line -> Platform.runLater(() -> serverControllers.get(server).getTextArea().appendText(line + System.lineSeparator())));
        }).start();
    }
}
```

**DashboardTabPane.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="dpc2dashboard.DashboardTabPaneController">
   <children>
      <BorderPane fx:id="borderPane" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
         <center>
            <ScrollPane fx:id="scrollPane" fitToHeight="true" fitToWidth="true" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
               <content>
                  <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                     <children>
                        <TextArea fx:id="textArea" editable="false" layoutX="7.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" wrapText="true" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
               </content>
               <BorderPane.margin>
                  <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
               </BorderPane.margin>
            </ScrollPane>
         </center>
         <top>
            <Button fx:id="button" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" BorderPane.alignment="TOP_LEFT">
               <BorderPane.margin>
                  <Insets left="5.0" top="5.0" />
               </BorderPane.margin>
            </Button>
         </top>
      </BorderPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**Dashboard.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<TabPane fx:id="tabPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="800.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="dpc2dashboard.DashboardController">
  <tabs>
    <Tab text="General">
         <content>
            <javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
               <children>
                  <BorderPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                     <center>
                        <ScrollPane fitToHeight="true" fitToWidth="true" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
                           <content>
                              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                                 <children>
                                    <TextArea fx:id="textArea" editable="false" layoutX="7.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" wrapText="true" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
                                 </children>
                              </AnchorPane>
                           </content>
                           <BorderPane.margin>
                              <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                           </BorderPane.margin>
                        </ScrollPane>
                     </center>
                     <top>
                        <Button fx:id="generalButton" mnemonicParsing="false" onMouseClicked="#handleGeneralButtonAction" text="Button" BorderPane.alignment="TOP_LEFT">
                           <BorderPane.margin>
                              <Insets left="5.0" top="5.0" />
                           </BorderPane.margin>
                        </Button>
                     </top>
                  </BorderPane>
               </children>
            </javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane>
         </content></Tab>
  </tabs>
</TabPane>
```

Currently it connects to the ping process, as I still need to figure out how to run my applications correctly outside of the IDE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## JavaFX Related

1. **main() method :** in *Dashboard.java* You do not need it. It's an IDE bug, It's only required for old IDEs. (I recommend using the latest NetBeans, version 8) from [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/hello_world.htm)

   > The `main()` method is not required for JavaFX applications when the JAR
   >   file for the application is created with the JavaFX Packager tool,
   >   which embeds the JavaFX Launcher in the JAR file. However, it is
   >   useful to include the `main()` method so you can run JAR files that were
   >   created without the JavaFX Launcher, such as when using an IDE in
   >   which the JavaFX tools are not fully integrated. Also, Swing
   >   applications that embed JavaFX code require the `main()` method.
2. **Use Toggle Buttons :** in *DashboardController.java* you are doing 
   `switch (generalButton.getText())` I suggest using `ToggleButton`s instead. It's built for toggling after all.
   from [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/toggle-button.htm)

   > Two or more toggle buttons can be combined into a group where only one button at a time can be selected

---

## Other

1. **Class Names :** The class `Server` can be refactored to something that reveals it's intent. I suggest `Process`. from Clean Code

   > It is easy to say that names should reveal intent.
2. **Package Names :** you are using package name `dpc2dashboard` which I think can be refactored to `dashboard` which would make more sense and more pronounceable. from Clean Code

   > Humans are good at words. A significant part of our brains is
   >   dedicated to the concept of words. And words are, by definition,
   >   pronounceable. It would be a shame not to take advantage of that huge
   >   portion of our brains that has evolved to deal with spoken lan- guage.
   >   So make your names pronounceable.